# ASP.NET MVC traffic Meter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm building my site with ASP.NET MVC 3. 
Each user will have 1 or many personal pages. I would like to meter traffic on each page.

I have searched various traffic meters and they all can meter domains, subdomains and stuff like that.

If someone has any experience with a similar problem I would appreciate some directions.

Best Regards

Comment: Is" traffic on each page" "hits" or "bandwidth"?

Answer (score 0):

I did just what you are asking for by writing data to a "WebHits" table in the database every time the user requested a page. The table tracks the date/time of the hit, who hit it, what they hit (the page) and a piece of user data which can be used to further detail the request.

Don't worry about one write operation per page unless you are expecting massive amounts of traffic.

Comment: Ok, but what if you had let's say video on that page. How do you know how much traffic did it take. Thnx

Comment: You want to know how many people are viewing the video? How is the video being served up? You're heading in the direction of web analytics. Google Analytcs is free and can help you but requires some learning and a bit of implementation. http://www.google.com/analytics/ You can also do it with web log analyzers but they are limited and passe.